# If zip runs out of space, will it save a partial zip?

Tags: zip, nohup

I have been running this command to zip each subdirectory into a zip file:

```
nohup sh -c 'for i in */; do zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i"; done' &
```

With that said, I ran out of space, and I am trying to figure out if any of the zip files would have been just partially done, or does it just fail a zip if it can't complete it? My nohup.out seems to indicate that if it can't complete the full zip, it does not make a partial zip. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

It does not create a partial zip file. I just did the following test.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test.dat bs=1M count=10 # create a 10MB file 
mkfs.ext4 test.dat #create ext4 filesystem in the file 
mount test.dat /mnt # mount the file to /mnt 
cd /mnt # go to the new device, which is only less than 10MB 
dd if=/dev/urandom of=test.dat bs=1M count=8 
zip test.zip test.dat
```

The zip command failed as there isn't enough space in /mnt and there's no zip file created.  And if you `strace` the process you can see that it creates a temporary file with a random filename while working:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "test.zip", O_RDONLY)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("test.dat", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=8388608, ...}) = 0
stat("test.zip", 0x5586eb6642e0)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("test.dat", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=8388608, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "test.zip", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
close(3)                                = 0
stat("test.zip", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
unlink("test.zip")                      = 0
getpid()                                = 16464
openat(AT_FDCWD, "zirEX4VT", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 3
```

As you can see from above trace, it created a file named `zirEX4VT`, then at the end of the trace:

```
write(1, "\nzip I/O error: No space left on"..., 39
zip I/O error: No space left on device) = 39
close(3)                                = 0
unlink("zirEX4VT")
```

The file `zirEX4VT` is removed.

Comment: You guys are awesome, thank you. Stack Exchange is amazing...